# Spring Datasource Close from custom factory

Tags: java, spring, datasource

As part of my application, I have to maintain multiple databases in a Spring Service.  So I have created `Datasource` dynamically and maintaining at Map.

Whenever client service requests, I am pulling the Datasource from Map (after validating the `Datasource` using `dataSource.getConnection().isValid(1)`) and perform business logic.

My concern is,

- Is Datasource would be closed when Service destroys?
- Do I need to create Datasource as a Bean and use `@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")`?
- If not, what is the best way to close the `Datasource`s.
- Is there any other best way to suit my need?

  ```
  @Service
  public class ClientDataSourceFactory {
  private Map<String, DataSource> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource>();

  public void getDataSource() {
      // Pre - Business Logic
      synchronized (this) {
      dataSource = map.get(key);
      boolean isValid = true;

      try (Connection con =  dataSource.getConnection()) {
          isValid = con.isValid(1);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          isValid = false;
      }

      if (!isValid) {
          // TODO: Need to close properly
          // ???
          map.remove(key);
          dataSource = null;
          // Create Datasource again using createDatasource() 
          // Store Datasource at Map with key
      }
      // Business Logic
  }

  @PreDestroy
  void preDestroy(){
      // TODO: Close all existing Datasources
      // ???
  }

  Datasource createDatasource(String key) {
      // fetch details using key 
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setUsername(username);
      dataSource.setPassword(password);
      dataSource.setUrl(url);
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
      return dataSource;
  }

  }
  ```

Comment: Since you have a local map with datasources, you need to manually destroy it. I am not sure whey you are having a custom class to manage DataSource, but I think it is not a better implementation.

Comment: any other way to maintain multiple datasources which would be created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can Inject multiple datasources as below, first configure all your data sources

```
@Configuration
  public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.secondary")
    @Qualifier("anotherDataSource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Now in your services inject the data sources you need,.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource primaryDataSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("anotherDataSource")
private DataSource secondaryDataSource;
```

Now add this in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.primary.url=jdbc:db2://host:50000/DEV1
spring.datasource.primary.username=dev1
spring.datasource.primary.password=password
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

spring.datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:db2://host:50000/DEV2
spring.datasource.secondary.username=dev2
spring.datasource.secondary.password=password
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

If you notice the above declaration names is similar to the datasource names in config class  **primary**  and **secondary**  [see prefix of @ConfigurationProperties]

**EDIT as per the comments.... I hope this helps**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

//use this as singleton
public class DataSourceCache {

    private final Map<String, DataSource> cache  = new HashMap<>();
    private final Lock dataSourceLock = new ReentrantLock();


    public DataSource creatOrget(String key) {

        Optional<DataSource> cachedDataSource = isCached(key);
        if(cachedDataSource.isPresent()) {
            return cachedDataSource.get();
        }

        try {
            dataSourceLock.lock();

            //check again for a valid cache created by another thread and return if exists
            cachedDataSource = isCached(key);
            if(cachedDataSource.isPresent()) {
                return cachedDataSource.get();
            }


            // fetch details using key or create your data source for key
            final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setUsername("username");
            dataSource.setPassword("password");
            dataSource.setUrl("url");
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("driverName");

            //cache the data source
            cache.put(key, dataSource);

            return dataSource;

        }finally {
            dataSourceLock.unlock();
        }
    }


    private Optional<DataSource> isCached(String key) {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = null;
        if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
            dataSource = BasicDataSource.class.cast(cache.get(key));
            if(dataSource != null && !dataSource.isClosed()) {
                return Optional.of(dataSource);
            }

            //if the code gets here means DS is cached but closed already, so lets remove it 
            cache.remove(key);
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    //write a pre destroy method here and do a clean up of all data sources by acquiring same dataSourceLock above

}
```

Comment: In my application, Database connectivity details would be fetched from other application dynamically and the application has the capability to modify or add new connections at any time.  So couldn't use this model as I don't know the number of datasource's during startup or after.

Comment: I see, in that case you can't use this solution, so you get data sources from another application? So you want to cache it locally for performance?

Comment: I get database connectivity details from other application.  Yes, I would like to cache the connections or data source for performance.
As part of current service, we have quartz scheduler which would fire a couple of queries at configured intervals.
Please suggest the better way.

Comment: @Bhupal edited the answer and added a cache implementation, hopefully it helps.